# Remote access to Registry Key with Windows 7

Tags: c#, registry, remote-access

my company is currently migrating to Windows 7, and I upgrade software to run with this system.
But we have a software that check Registry Key by remote connection.
And now the fun stuff, a very simple method :

```
/// <summary>
/// Contoler cle registre
/// </summary>
/// <param name="posteClient">Poste client</param>
/// <returns>Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey</returns>
protected RegistryKey Initialiser(string cle, string posteClient)
{
    RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, posteClient);
    regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(cle, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl);
    return regKey;
}
```

is not working with Windows 7 (no problem on XP SP3)
I'm Network Administrator on Windows 7 (remote machine) and Windows XP (local machine from where the software is launched).

1. The first issue is when I give DNS name for remote machine, the error "Network path not found" is throw, DNS name is well known => checked by nslookup. With IP instead, there is no issue.
2. When OpenSubKey is reached, another error "Access is denied", whatever I up the methods with FullControl parameters.

So how can I connect to remote registry key on Windows 7 (and obviously that run ever on Windows XP).

To be more accurate, the software is executed on Windows XP and access is denied when I try to connect on remote machine that run Windows 7. If remote machine is Windows XP, then there is no issue.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: does remote registry service is running on BOTH machines ?

Comment: Can you connect to the remote registry via regedit, using the same credentials your code uses ?

Comment: Yes, it's running fine now! On Windows 7, I do activate RemoteRegistry Service before. Thank you :)